# テーブルthタグの内容を取得して、動的にCSS設定したい

Tags: javascript, css

**下記thタグより表示文字を取得して、**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>★</th>
      <th>大阪</th>
      <th>沖縄</th>
      <th>東京</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>


├───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┤
│ ★　   │大阪    │沖縄   │東京 │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
```

**下記CSSを動的生成するには、どうすれば良いでしょうか？**

```
td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "大阪";}
td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "沖縄";}
td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "東京";}
```

Comment: アスキーアートなどではなく、実際の HTML タグを記載なさる方がよいと思います。

Comment: HTML タグを追記しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javascriptで書いてみましたが、別の方法が良いと思います。
以下のコードは、tableタグより後に置かないと動きません。

```
var th_elem = document.querySelectorAll('th');
var text_th;
var css_str = '<style>';
for(var i = 0; i < th_elem.length; i++) {
    text_th = th_elem[i].textContent;
    if((text_th !== "") && (text_th !== "*")){
        css_str += 'td:nth-of-type('+(i+1)+'):before { content: "'+text_th+'";}\n';
    }
}
css_str += '</style>';
document.write(css_str);
```

Comment: 期待通り動作したのですが、「別の方法が良いと思います」はどういう意味でしょうか？ document.writeを使用しているから？？？

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('th') の動きが遅いと思います。

Comment: なるほど。回答ありがとうございました